# usage of continue loop, and or

Tags: python

I'm quite new in Python. I have searched on site but I couldn't find solution for that pease show me if I missed.

I am trying to understand loops and "and" "or" I did some experiment with these elements but I confused.

Bellow code I was expecting code pass the numbers which isn't dividable by 3 or 5 and print rest. But suprisingly It print the numbers which is dividable by 15! (other words which is dividable by 3 and 5)

```
for x in range(100):
    if x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0:
        continue
    print(x)
```

**output:**
0
15
30
45
60
75
90

And this one I was expecting it will pass the number which isn't dividable 3 and 5 But it prints the numbers which is dividable 3 or 5 as I wanted in my first example.

```
for x in range(100):
    if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0:
        continue
    print(x)
```

**output:**
0
3
5
6
9
10
12
15
18
20
.............

I don't understand what I am missing. I'm aware that I can make it happen with if, elif and else form but I wanted to learn more about "continue" usage. I'd appereciate if you help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Each of these concepts is explained in detail in any tutorial on the topic.  Instead of combining loops and boolean operators, give us an example of only one of these, and explain *exactly* where you get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an easier time understanding what's happening just by walking through the numbers and seeing what your logic does for each number.  You have walked into a logic equivalence that can be confusing, and is expressed in [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  Essentially you can say

```
(x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0) = !(x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0)
```

so your first logic test is checking whether a number is divisible by both 3 and 5, which are the multiples of 15.  And your second test is

```
x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0 = !(x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

so you are testing whether a number is divisible by either 3 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear up the `or` logic like this:

```
for x in range(100):
    if x % 3 != 0:  # skip 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16....
        continue    
    if x % 5 != 0:  # skip 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16...
        continue    
    print(x)  # only numbers that pass both checks 0,15,30,...
```

With this, only 0, 15, 30, ... get through

If you convert it with boolean algebra,

```
if x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0:
```

is the same as

```
if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
```

which gives the same results (0,15,30,...)

Comment: Got it! I understand contniue better now Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` keyword will essentially end the current iteration of the loop, and jump directly to the start of the loop to re-evaluate the loop condition (see https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html).

So, in your first block of code, any time `x` is not divisible by 3 or 5, it will not print the number, meaning the only numbers which are printed are those which are divisible by both 3 and 5.

Comment: Got it! I understand contniue better now Thanks!